# Display .doc inside a div

Tags: javascript, html, .doc

It is possible to display a pdf inside a div using this:

```
<div>
    <object data="test.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="300" height="200">
    PDF : <a href="test.pdf">test.pdf</a>
    </object>
</div>
```

Is it possible to do something similar for a .doc or .docx? (without server side)

- I am assuming the browser or the computer has a way of reading the data.

Comment: yes, when a suitable browser-plugin is available

Comment: look at this: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js and http://andreasgal.com/2011/06/15/pdf-js/ I never used it, so I don't know how mature this is

Comment: Possible duplicate of [word document viewer browser plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5001497/990877)

Comment: You will probably need to convert the `.doc`. The only reason you can display pdfs in browser is because of the adobe reader plugin or chrome pdf viewer. To convert a `.doc` to html, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253834/convert-doc-to-html-in-php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Might I suggest Google Doc Viewer, it'll allow you up show several types of files inline where they would normally prompted for download:

https://docs.google.com/viewer/

You can also use this inline in your own website with the use of an iframe.

Here is a list of supported file-types:

- Microsoft Word (.DOC and .DOCX)
- Microsoft Excel (.XLS and .XLSX)
- Microsoft PowerPoint (.PPT and .PPTX)
- Adobe Portable Document Format (.PDF)
- Apple Pages (.PAGES)
- Adobe Illustrator (.AI)
- Adobe Photoshop (.PSD)
- Tagged Image File Format (.TIFF)
- Autodesk AutoCad (.DXF)
- Scalable Vector Graphics (.SVG)
- PostScript (.EPS, .PS)
- TrueType (.TTF)
- XML Paper Specification (.XPS)
- Archive file types (.ZIP and .RAR)

I messed around with this for mobile output of PDFs but the mobile version had an error that made it impossible to use. Not sure where the development on this product has landed but the desktop version always worked very well.

Comment: A reason for the down-vote would be much appreciated. As far as I know this is the easiest way to display content inline that would otherwise need a plugin to view...

Comment: Thanks, sorry this fell through the cracks as not getting answered, but very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this through an iframe inside the div by linking the source to the path of the file on your server.

```
<div>
<iframe src="mydoc.docx">myDocument</iframe>
</div>

<div>
<iframe src="mydoc.xslx">myDocument</iframe>
</div>

<div>
<iframe src="mydoc.pdf">myDocument</iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: The user's browser will still have to have a plugin that knows what a `.docx` file is, otherwise it will just prompt the user to download the file.

Comment: This wants to download the content, and is not displaying it... any suggestions?

Comment: @chrisFrisina Unless the user has a plugin downloaded for their browser that allows them to view `.doc` files inline, they will be prompted to download the file. Google Doc Viewer is a way around this: https://docs.google.com/viewer/?pli=1