# Viewing of Word file in browser

Tags: php, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [word document viewer browser plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001497/word-document-viewer-browser-plugin)

I wan to view the user uploaded docx file on front end (browser). Any recommendation for jQuery or in flash or in PHP .

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks... I try to use http://webodf.org/start/ , but it not allow to opne .docx , the reason is where i have to view the files are on intranet .

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do it with Flash or PHP... or pretty much any modern language

1. Decode uploaded file, extracting text, formatting and graphics
2. Create image or pdf from this information
3. Display #2 in the browser